# wordpress USER REGISTRATION forms or contact form 7

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7, user-registration

To the point, I need my registration form to have a field (dropdown or multiple choice) would prevent the customer to carry on any further.

e.g. If a field asks to pick "yes" or "no", if the customer chooses 'No' then a message will show saying "we are sorry but you cannot continue with registration online, please contact the admin desk directly"

Answer (score 0):

Use the WordPress User Registration form for registration purpose as it has all the plumbing already built-in for it...doing it with a CF7/custom form would require additional coding to handle the registration.

However, to enable the functionality you are seeking in your question, you could do it simply using a javascript code fired with a simple HTML form,

```
<!-- HTML for the landing page-->
<form>
  <label> Do you want to register online?
    <select id="online-registration">
      <option value="yes"> yes </option>
      <option value="no"> no </option>
    </select>
  </label>
</form>
<script>
(function( $ ) {
  'use strict';
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#online-registration').on('change',function(){
      var $this = $(this);
      if('yes'==$this.val()){
        //redirect to the WP registration page.
      }else{
        //display a pop-up to contact the admin.
      }
    })
  });

})( jQuery );
</script>
```